# Getting jupyter output in Google Colab

Tags: bash, shell, jupyter-notebook, stdout, google-colaboratory

We need to see the output (stdout) that is generated by the jupyter notebook in google colab. Doing some investigation it seems that the output is piped up all the way to the main process:

root         1     0  0 Jun27 ?        00:00:00 /bin/bash -e /datalab/run.sh

The pipeline that the output runs through seems to be as follows:

- /usr/bin/python2 /usr/local/bin/jupyter-notebook .....
- /tools/node/bin/node /datalab/web/app.js
- node /tools/node/bin/forever ..... /datalab/web/app.js
- /bin/bash -e /datalab/run.sh

Any ideas on how I could access it?

---

I just discovered that `forever` doesn't forward the output from `app.js`. `forever list` suggests that the output is going to `/content/.forever/BQBW.log` which doesn't exist. I still don't understand why nor if this is really where stdout ends up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up writing a c++ wrapper for cout and py::print that can be used to enable or disable python printing. Pretty disgusting given the fact that I needed to change my entire c++ source to use the wrapper instead of std::cout.

Answer (score 2):

Use [wurlitzer](https://github.com/minrk/wurlitzer). Here's a full example:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jpAOdWJDCh_YzmqidGnlYHHCFODNKQkB

This notebook:

1. Saves a C file that prints to stdout.
2. Compiles as a shared library.
3. Loads the shared library into the running Python backend.
4. Uses wurlitzer to capture the output when invoking the library.

Comment: Big thanks, tested wurlitzer on colab and locally with jupyter but I still don't get output. In the program the kernel is dying which is why I need the output. Despite the dying wurlitzer.sys_pipes should give me something. In the local jupyter shell I get output. When using sys_pipes not only is the shell output gone but also I don't get anything inside jupyter.

Answer (score 2):

(I realize you're unblocked, but leaving this answer here to hopefully help future travelers)

Wurlitzer uses a thread to flush its pipes, and I guess your C++ code was crashing before its pipe was flushed. 
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1i6x882Dn6E5PwaptVQ4ADGyEvBZAHm7i shows an example where TF C++ code emits dev placement to stderr and then is killed before execution completes. Flushing quickly results in all the output showing up before the kernel is killed, but leaving it at the default (0.2s) results in partial or no output showing up.

If the output you want is an assert/FATAL message right before process death, wurlitzer's approach is unlikely to work for you, and running as a subprocess is likely to be a faster iteration path, e.g. write the code you'd have in the cell out to a file e.g. using `%%writefile` and then run a subprocess python like:
`!python3 file.py`
Any stdout/stderr the subprocess emits (whether from python code writing to sys.std{out,err} or C++ code writing to fd={1,2}) should show up in the cell's output.

Answer (score 1):

Is the output you're looking for coming from your code or from Jupyter itself?

If it's jupyter, it takes a little work to enable logging -- here's a full example: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1q2mhsj4bwwdQK-KZIxrIIKed8O11MQl0

Comment: I tried both `with capture_logs():  my_code` and `with print_logs():  my_code` and it doesn't work. I think it's not jupyter's output. I start jupyter-notebook in the shell and in that same shell I see the output of the c++ code appearing. But in my understanding c++ prints directly (not through jupyter) to that shell. I also tried it with the higher log level.

Comment: I still don't think I understand what you're doing, but it sounds like you're unblocked; in the future, sharing a notebook with sample code is likely to be the most effective.

Comment: I would have liked to share but sharing a notebook backed with c++ code in the way I have it set up is very difficult. Already took me 2+ days to get it working on colab